# Results Differs in ACR Cloud APP and Web Api

Tags: php, acrcloud

I am using ACR cloud WEB API for fetching Metadata of Music

WEB API code : https://github.com/acrcloud/webapi_example/blob/master/identify%20protocol%201%20(recommended)/IdentifyProtocolV1.php

The API processed and gives result as count 11 but ACR App give the results as count 28..

I am messed..why this happens...Why results is varied from api and app..

Kindly Help me on this......

Thankz in Advance

Answer (score 0):

i think it depends on how many queries you send to ACRCloud for matching. If we think about one same query from ACRCloud from api or from sdk, the result should the same.